# Get Value from a Label in a Template for a Listboxitem

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

My problem is that I need the `Value` of a `Label` in a `Template` as a *string*. Its a `Template` for a `ListBoxItem` with a `CheckBox` and a `Label`. When the box get checked I need the `Value` of the `Label` as a string variable in the code.

`ListBox`

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="196" Margin="10,24,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" BorderBrush="#FF7799BB" 
             Name="ListBoxTblColumns" DataContextChanged="TableColumns_DataContextChanged" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="columnSelectBox" Margin="0,7,4,0" Checked="columnSelectBox_Checked" Unchecked="columnSelectBox_Unchecked"/>
                <Label Name="lblColName" Content="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

And in this event I want to get the value from `lblColName`:

```
public void columnSelectBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    string colName = ...;
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Since the `Label` is simply binding to the DataContext and since `CheckBox` has the same DataContext, you can use `(sender as CheckBox).DataContext.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: I actually don't understand what you wanna do, can you give me an example? Cause, I guess it can be done by Bindings only.